# Wordpress ecommerce digital download dynamic products

Tags: wordpress, download, e-commerce, digital-downloads

Can someone tell me how can I have dynamic digital products in Wordpress E commerce please?

i.e, I have a database of information from which I can generate reports. I want the user to be able to search for keywords, using which I can search database and generate report. The cost of the report is generated from DB dynamically. Now I display the result to the user and I want to be able to add this product to the cart.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's some pretty heavy lifting for WP with WP ecommerce. You want:
- The user to be able to dynamically generate reports
- The cost of the report is also dynamic

Those two features are possible, but not really combined with that setup. I would suggest rethinking your business model so that it's something which is more common (and thus more likely supported.)

Some examples:
- Charge users to access the site, allow them to generate reports for a flat daily/weekly/monthly... fee
- Offer predefined reports. You could potentially offer variants of reports which would somewhat act like dynamic pricing.

If you can setup predefined reports, you could potentially set them up so that the download link passes parameters in the URL to a web service that pulls content for the report from a database.